# Jquery find text after text which is present in strong tag inside grandparent

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="col-12">
     <div class="d-block">
              <strong>Product code:</strong> 
              <span class="">L00335.06</span>
     </div>
     <div class="d-block">
              <span class="">L00335.06</span>
               <span class="card-text text-muted">Catalog number: ALF-L00335-06</span>
     </div>
    <strong class="text-capitalize">quantity:</strong> 5g&nbsp;
    <strong class="text-capitalize">CAS:</strong> 2981-10-4&nbsp;
    <div class="d-block mt-2 checkoutHide">
       <span class="js-delete-item pointer" data-entrynumber="0" data-quantity="1"><strong class="icon_Remove font_icon"></strong> Delete</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

This my code now what my requirement is that i want to find 'L0035.06' using click or hover on 'js-delete-item' but here in code you can see 'L00335.06' in two 'd-block' classes .I want to find 'L00335.06' only if it's brother is 'Product code'.Example in first 'd-block' class.

What is did is :

```
var id = $('.jsdeleteitem').parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().find("span").text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly the selector is `.js-delete-item`, not `.jsdeleteitem`. Secondly, you need to bind an event handler to that element so your code runs when it's clicked, not when the DOM loads. Lastly you can simplify the DOM traversal by using `closest()` and `find()` instead of chained `prev()` calls. This also makes the logic more robust to HTML changes. Try this:

```js
$('.js-delete-item').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".d-block:contains('Product code') span").text().trim();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="d-block">
    <strong>Product code:</strong>
    <span class="">L00335.06</span>
  </div>
  <div class="d-block">
    <span class="">L00335.06</span>
    <span class="card-text text-muted">Catalog number: ALF-L00335-06</span>
  </div>
  <strong class="text-capitalize">quantity:</strong> 5g&nbsp;
  <strong class="text-capitalize">CAS:</strong> 2981-10-4&nbsp;
  <div class="d-block mt-2 checkoutHide">
    <span class="js-delete-item pointer" data-entrynumber="0" data-quantity="1">
      <strong class="icon_Remove font_icon"></strong> 
      Delete
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir the position of div may change.Can you please provide the solution only where sibling strong tag contains text 'Product code'.I have mentioned this in question.Thanks

Comment: Your question said the first `.d-block` class, so I used `:first`. I've updated the answer for you so it's now based on `:content()` instead